# The condition not working for int in case of "= 0"

Tags: php, sql

i am trying to execute this query but it is not working correctly.

```
SELECT *
        FROM posts P
        LEFT JOIN post_status PS ON PS.post_id = P.post_id
        LEFT JOIN users U ON U.user_id = P.post_author
        WHERE
        P.post_cat = '5'
        AND P.is_hide = '0'
        ORDER BY post_views DESC
        LIMIT 8
```

i want to filter those posts having "is_hide" field is 0. but it  also shows the result that have value is_hide = 1.
Where is problem..

Comment: What is the datatype of `is_hide`?

Comment: it's just a field name

Comment: `P` is an alias of `posts`, the table (or view, whatever) in the `FROM` clause. Therefore, `P.is_hide` should refer to the corresponding column in the database of some type. What is the type of that column in the database? If it's a numeric type, then single quotes around `0` should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your query appears to be missing a `where` clause.

```
SELECT *
    FROM posts P
    LEFT JOIN post_status PS ON PS.post_id = P.post_id
    LEFT JOIN users U ON U.user_id = P.post_author
    WHERE P.post_cat = 5
    AND P.is_hide = 0
    ORDER BY post_views DESC
    LIMIT 8
```

Also, on top of this, if these are integer columns you should compare directly and not single quote.

Comment: i added it, i forget here by mistake

Comment: try removing the quotes around 5 and 0.